# visual studio new project "ok" button greyed out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would assume this just means I'm missing a dependency, but I cant create ANY type of project (console application, web app, windows form, etc.).  I am running VS 2012 premium.

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps post a screen shot?

Comment: Did the Project Templates not get installed properly? Yes, a scren shot would be helpful here.

Comment: I added a screenshot. everything seemed to install fine, how do i double check this?  I am also unable to browse a SQL DW Cube if that is related somehow at all...

Comment: The Location setting looks unhappy, that's normally a complete path.  Like c:\foo\bar\ConsoleApplication1.  It won't let you create projects in directories that are not writable, like c:\program files.  No idea why it would behave that way (I changed my settings), Tool + Options, Projects and Solutions, "Projects location" setting must refer to a writable directory.  Unticking the "Save new projects when created" could be another workaround.  Or click Browse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably attempting to save your projects to a directory location for which you do not have write permission. It might be a network drive somewhere. Changing it to a local directory worked for me.